# Erro ao rodar exe de programa feito em c++ em outro computador

Tags: c, c++, dll

Fiz um código em c++ com a biblioteca fstream e gostaria que meus amigos testassem ele, mas toda hora que eles abrem o arquivo exe do programa só da erro dizendo que falta arquivos dll, Sou novo no meio da programação então se alguém puder me dizer qual foi o meu erro e o como faço pra consertar ele.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


int main(void) {

//Cria o objeto de arquivo
ofstream arquivodesaida;
//Abre o aruivo ou cria caso não exista
arquivodesaida.open("Texto.txt", std::ios_base::app);
//Escreve algo
arquivodesaida << "Ola mundo";
//Fecha o arquivo
arquivodesaida.close();

system("start Texto.txt");
return 0;





 }
```

Comment: É difícil diagnosticar o problema com tão pouca informação. Você pode complementar sua pergunta editando-a e inserindo qual foi o compilador usado, versão do sistema operacional no qual está tentando executar o programa etc. [Este link para o Stack Overflow em Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297270/problems-with-running-exe-file-built-with-visual-studio-on-another-computer) contém algumas informações caso tenha compilado seu programa com o Visual Studio no Windows.

Comment: Eu compilei ele no visual studio 2019, Estou usando o windows 10 pro versão 20H2

Comment: Provavelmente falta instalar o runtime do Visual C++ da versão que você está usando, vai ser um pacote cujo nome começa com MSVC*. Tem para fazer download público disponibilizado pela MS.

Comment: Cara sou muito novo com relação a isso, Eu tenho que baixar isso na minha maquina ou na maquina dos meus amigos? E onde eu encontro esses arquivos? pode me mandar um link?

Comment: @Follkss você pode encontrar as versões do Visual C++ [neste link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0) e **instalar na máquina onde quer executar o programa**.

Comment: Faça uma pesquisa pelas versões do *Visual C++ Redistributable*. A própria documentação da Microsoft tem informações sobre como instalar, versões de instalação, configurações no Visual Studio etc.

Comment: Mais teria algum jeito da pessoa rodar meu programa no computador dela sem precisar baixar nada não ?  Ou se precisasse de qualquer jeito teria como fazer o meu programa obrigar a pessoa baixar os arquivos necessários para rodar ?

Comment: Não. Provavelmente não tem. Quando você instala um programa numa máquina tem certos pré-requisitos e é por isso que tem em geral um programa de set-up. Tem que ver as versões de várias coisas, gravar coisas no registro do Windows, registrar ícones e atalhos e coisas assim. A versão oficial do Visual Studio tem um instalador, a versão paga. E tem caras que vendem instaladores também. Parece que há uma maneira de usar isso na versão community, mas não sei se é fato. Por outo lado, se você comprou o Visual Studio tem isso em algum lugar.

Comment: Eu não uso o MVSC, mas em tese deveria funcionar. Você mandou compilar em formato Debug ou produção? Se em produção não estiver funcionando, tenta compilar com o Mingw (Codeblocks e DevC++ usam o Mingw).

Answer (score -2):

Consegui resolver de uma maneira o meu problema:

Tive que ir nas configurações do projeto e colocar:

C/C++ -> Code generation -> Runtime library -> Multi-threaded (/MT)

E pra compilar tive que colocar (Release e x64),  A partir disso quando o meu amigo testou o programa, parou de dar erros de dll.

Answer (score -3):

Compilei no CodeBlocks e executei a sua rotina e funcionou sem problema.
Também sou novo em C++ então não entendi porque você colocou int main(void) ao invés de int main().
Também retirei [, std::ios_base::app] e a rotina continuou funcionando.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ok muito obrigado irei dar uma olhada aqui

Comment: Olá man, o problema e que quando eu vou executar o arquivo em um  computador de um amigo meu da erro de dll

Comment: Tentou compilar no CodeBlock?